# Best way to start a project: OpenCV + GUI (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, mfc, project

Hey this is my first question here on stackoverflow, allow me to add that i'm a newbie in programming.

Which would be the best or the "right" way/approach to start a OpenCV with a friendly GUI (not console based) software.

Which IDE should i be using to achieve this ?
I have Visual Studio 2012 and Qt.

**1.Empty CLR Project**

> File -> New -> Project -> VC++ -> CLR-> CLR Empty Project

Then:

> Project -> Add New Item -> VC++ -> UI -> Windows Form

**2. MFC Application**

> File -> New -> Project ->  VC++ -> MFC -> MFC Application

I've also searched for Emgu CV which seems to be working better with C#.

What about Qt ???

Thank you in advance

Comment: do not put the cart before the horse. first develop an algorithm, then think about gui, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Try Code blocks or Visual Studio 2013.
I would prefer VS2013 if I was you.

Comment: Well i've been using code blocks for some time , but only for console applications. Regarding Visual Studio, which i think i prefer over the code blocks ide, which project should i choose in vs to start with ? Console application with opencv seems to be working best , but i want a friendly GUI